# How to convert directory path to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a directory structure path like 
**root/path1/path2/path3** 
I want this to be

```
Array(
[0] => "root"
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "path1"
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => "path2"
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "path3"
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Comment: use explode("/", $path) but why would you want so many nested arrays?

Comment: explode giving me single dimensional array, like
Array
(
    [0] => root
    [1] => path1
    [2] => path2
    [3] => path3
)

Thats is the path i get from my scraping script i need to create similar directory and subdirectory. mkdir("root/path1/path2",0755,true) will create one but i need to do some string function on directory name so I need them individually.

Hope you got my idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input  = 'root/path1/path2/path3';
$output = null;

foreach (array_reverse(explode('/', $input)) as $part) {
    $output = $output ? array($part, $output) : array($part);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'root' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'path1' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'path2' (length=5)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'path3' (length=5)
```

Comment: any idea how you could reverse this to get the string from the array??